# xargs みたいなことをしたい、ただし、 -I をすべての引数の前に付与したい

Tags: linux, shellscript

xargs みたいなことをしたいです。
ただし、 -I をすべての引数の前に付与したいです。

例:

```
: 入力
foo
bar
piyo

: 実行してほしいコマンド
some_command -I foo -I bar -I piyo
```

特に、 ARG_MAX の処理を適切に行ってほしいと考えているのですが、これを実現する方法などありますか？

Comment: `-I` と引数の間にスペースは必要ですか？ `-Ifoo` などとしても構わないのであれば `...| sed 's/^/-I/' | xargs some_command` とできるのですが。また、`-I` に対応するロングオプションがあれば `sed 's/^/--longoption=/'` とするなどの対応も考えられます。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

shellscript というタグが付いてたので、シェルスクリプト（bash限定）で `xargs` もどきの実装と、そこに `-I` 追加を埋め込んでみました:

```
#!/bin/bash
# ${#var} が文字数でなくバイト数を返してくれる…はず。
LC_ALL=C

readonly ARG_MAX=$(getconf ARG_MAX)
# -1 の hex 表現からポインターサイズを推測
readonly PTR_SIZE=$(( $(printf "%x" -1 | wc -c) / 2 ))

# 与えられた引数のそのまま配列にコピー
args_base=("$@")

# 与えられた引数と環境変数のバイト数の計算
declare -i i len_base
joined="$*"
# 最後の引数以外、終端の \0 は空白に置き換えられているので、
# 最後の引数分だけ +1
len_base=$((${#joined} + 1))
len_base+=$(( PTR_SIZE * $# ))
# 環境変数の \0 は \n で置き換えられているので値はそのまま
len_base+=$(env | wc -c)
len_base+=$(( PTR_SIZE * $(env | wc -l) ))

exit_status=0
declare -a args
declare -i len

#######################################
# global 変数 args と len を初期化
# Globals:
#   args (modified)
#   len (modified)
#   args_base
#   len_base
# Arguments:
#   None
# Returns:
#   None
#######################################
function command::reset(){
  args=("${args_base[@]}")
  len=${len_base}
}
#######################################
# コマンドを実行
# Globals:
#   args
#   len
#   len_base
# Arguments:
#   erro_if_no_arg: "false" が与えられた場合、入力がなくてもエラーにしない
# Returns:
#   args の終了ステータス、何も実行しなかった場合には 0
#######################################
function command::run(){
  local error_if_no_arg="${1:-true}"
  if ((len == len_base)); then
    if ${error_if_no_arg}; then
      # 入力が ARG_MAX-4 より大きい場合、追加の引数なしでここが実行される
      echo 'one of given item is too long' 1>&2
      exit 126
    fi
    return 0
  fi
  "${args[@]}" < /dev/null
  local status="$?"
  if [ $status -gt 0 ]; then
    exit_status=123
  fi
}

command::reset
while read line; do
  # +4 is for "-I\0" and "\0" for $line
  if ((len + 4 + ${#line} + PTR_SIZE * 2 >= ARG_MAX)); then
    command::run
    command::reset
  fi
  args+=(-I "$line")
  ((len += 4 + ${#line} + PTR_SIZE * 2)) || :
done
command::run false
exit $exit_status
```

というファイルを、例えば `xargs_i.sh` と作成して

```
引数生成コマンド | xargs_i.sh some_command
```

とすれば、多分、それっぽい動作をするかと思います。

> 特に、 ARG_MAX の処理を適切に

ということなので、その辺は頑張ってバイト数を計算するようにしてみましたが、やたらサンプルが長くなってしまいました。頑張ってないところとして

- 「引数生成コマンド」が何も出力しない場合、何もしない (`xargs` の場合、追加引数なしでコマンドを実行するっぽい）
- エラーハンドリングは適当なので、非正常系の動作は `xargs` コマンドと異なる部分が多々ある
- これをベースに `xargs -0` 相等の動作に改造するのはほぼ不可能
- バイト数を計算する都合上、勝手に `LC_ALL=C` をセットしている(ので、locale に依存するコマンドは期待した通りに動かない）

などがあります。

Comment: クオート(というより、その中にはいっているスペース)を正しく処理させられそうなので、 accept します。

Comment: ちなみに上のスクリプトは `xargs -d'\n'` 相等です。入力サンプルが改行区切りっぽかったのでそうなってます。「xargs **みたいな** 」ということなのでこれでいいと思いますが、念の為。

Answer (score 1):

下記は`ARG_MAX`の考慮は`xargs`にしてもらう例です。
組み立てたコマンドは`sh`に渡していますが、並行処理させたい場合は再度`xargs`や`parallel`に渡すとよいと思います。

```
引数生成コマンド |sed "s/$/ -I/" |xargs echo some_command -I |sed "s/^some_command -I -I/some_command -I/; s/ -I$//" |sh
```

流れ：

- `sed`で全ての引数の後ろに`-I`を付ける。
  前に付けるのが素直だが、`ARG_MAX`の関係上、後から足す事は避けたい。余分な`-I`は出来ても、足りなくは成らないように、こうしておく。
- `xargs`で先頭を`some_command -I`としたコマンド列にする。
  この段階で引数が多ければ、`xargs`が複数行にしてくれる。
- `sed`で不要な`-I`を削除。先頭付近でダブっているか、行末にあるはず。

---

引数毎にプロセスを生成してよいなら`xargs`の`-I`オプションで可能ですが当然遅いです。

```
引数生成コマンド |xargs -I {} some_command -I {}
```

Comment: 引数がクオートなしの文字列であることが保障されていれば、これで実現が出来ますね。